# Marshal a Memory<byte> to a native function expecting byte[]

Tags: c#

I am trying to wrap the BIO portion of OpenSSL in c#. I am trying to expose BIOs as IDuplexPipes.

BIOs have a `read(byte[] buffer, int length)` function. As you can see, the BIO is expecting a `byte[]` but the `PipeWriter` provides only `Memory<byte>`.

The imported function looks like this:

```
[DllImport(DLLNAME, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern static int BIO_read(IntPtr b, byte[] buf, int len);
```

which is then wrapped like this in BIO class:

```
public int Read(byte[] buffer, int length)
{
    return SSL.BIO_read(Handle, buffer, length);
}
```

The pipe's code looks like this:

```
public async void DoReadAsync()
{
    var writer = _inputPipe.Writer;

    while(true)
    {
        Memory<byte> mem = writer.GetMemory(_sizeHint);

        _bio.Read(mem???, _sizeHint); <- here is my confusion.
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm hoping to avoid copying the data read from the BIO to the mem, and instead would like to provide the `Memory<bytes>`'s "byte array" directly to `BIO.read(..)`. Also, I would like to take advantage of the `MemoryPool<byte>` with `writer.GetMemory()` rather than creating new `Memory<bytes>`s.

I'm not as good at interop as I'd like to be, and I am not finding anything on google that helps.

Comment: You can Pin the Memory<> buffer and get a pointer from that, which you should be able to use in your interop call.

Comment: Is this what you had in mind? `(IntPtr)GCHandle.Alloc(mem, GCHandleType.Pinned)`

Comment: Not exactly --- I noticed the Memory<> type has a Pin method, but I must admit that I have not yet had a need to try it out myself.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError yeah unfortunately that gives me a `MemoryHandle`... I'm even less familiar with that but it seems there is no obvious way to cast that to IntPtr...

Comment: Did you ever come to a resolution for this issue as I am facing the same problem using the Android.Hardware.Usb.UsbDeviceConnection.BulkTransfer(… , byte[] buffer buffer, …) function which I can't change or update to use a Span<T> or Memory<T>, really frustrating me today!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interop Services provides a means to get an ArraySegment which can be accessed as an array.

> **TryGetArray(ReadOnlyMemory, ArraySegment)**
>
> Tries to get an array segment from the underlying memory buffer. The return value indicates the success of the operation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices?view=netcore-3.0

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

//Turn memory space into ArraySegment for port use
if (!MemoryMarshal.TryGetArray(memory, out ArraySegment<byte> arraySegment))
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Buffer backed by array was expected");
}

int bytesRead = port.Read(arraySegment.Array, 1000);
```

Comment: This solution was inspired by example code from https://programmer.group/constructing-net-communication-program-with-high-performance-pipelines.html